# Vue : hide button when no action taken

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my code below i want to hide button remove all when no category selected, and when i select a category it should show and hide again when clicked, i tried code below but it didn't work, any help ? and thanks in advnace

```html
<template>

           <b-button v-if="!AddCategory === []" size="sm" variant="outline-secondary"  @click="RemoveAll"> X Remove all</b-button>
          </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row class="categories-row">
            <div
              class="categories"
              v-for="(category, index) in categories"
              :key="index"
              @click="Add(category._id, index)"
              :class="[selectedIndex.includes(index) ? 'green' : 'gray']"
              required
            >
           {{ category.category_name }} 
            </div>
          </b-row>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "postComponent",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [],
      file_path: null,
      selectedIndex: [],
      isediting: false,
      AddCategory: [],
      error: [],

      
    };
  },
  methods: {
  
    Add(AddCategory, index) {

      if (this.selectedIndex.includes(index)) this.Remove(index);
      else this.selectedIndex.push(index);
      this.AddCategory.push(AddCategory);
    },
    
    RemoveAll() {
      this.AddCategory = [];
      this.selectedIndex.splice(this.AddCategory);
     
    },
    </script>
```

Comment: does the console show any error? I would try to move the expression in v-if to a function, or compare its length, if it's zero, it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `AddCategory.length >0` in `v-if`
OR
best way of doing that with v-model https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html